# 3D Array Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, python, vectorization

I have $2$ matrices ($A$ with shape $(5,2,3)$ and $B$ with shape $(5,3,8)$), and I want to perform some kind of multiplication in order to take a new matrix with shape $(5,2,8)$.

Pseudo Code:

```
 for i= 0 to A.dim[0] do:
       C[i] = A[i].dot(B[i])
```

Is it possible to do the above operation without using a loop?

Comment: Given the tags, I'm assuming that this is in Python rather than, say, matlab. Is there a reason you don't like the loop? Surely you could do it with a comprehension or something, but that's roughly the same thing. Are you hoping to somehow improve big-O runtime? Or is it just the extra line of code that's bugging you? [You could, of course, write a general tensor-contraction library and share it with the world. And that library would contain... a loop.]

Answer (score 0):

The correct Python syntax would be `for i in range(A.shape[0])` and would use `matmul` instead of `dot`, but you don't want the for loop anyway. You could write `C=np.array([a.matmul(b) for a, b in zip(A, B)])`, which is a declarative comprehension rather than an imperative for loop. But better still is [np.tensordot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576973/python-numpy-matrix-multiplication-in-high-dimension), `C=np.tensordot(A, B, axes=((0, 2), (0, 1)))`.

Alternatively, another answer at the same link recommends `C=np.einsum('nmk,nkj->nmj', A, B)`.

Comment: ...and that's the general tensor-contraction library I was talking about.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yeah, with questions like this the trick is "how should you do it in numpy?" *Part* of the motive is a concise declarative alternative to imperative for loops, but the main reason for numpy is [speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944367/are-numpys-basic-operations-vectorized-i-e-do-they-use-simd-operations).